# Make device driver for parallel port DB25

Tags: c, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I am beginner in device driver. i can make simple character device driver with simple apis (eg. open,close,read,write). so i have basic knowledge of char device driver. and i want to make driver for Parallel port DB25.

Answer (score 3):

Chapter 9 of the Linux Device Drivers book [1] has concrete examples for hardware control and I/O. It also covers implementing a simple parallel port driver. Later chapters cover interrupts, DMA, and PCI devices, which would be a good next step afterward.

**[1] Linux Device Drivers -- Chapter 9: Communicating with Hardware**

http://lwn.net/Kernel/LDD3/

Comment: Yes, but it's totally theoretical, and little bit harder. i want practical code for that.
i got it from this site : 
"http://www.freesoftwaremagazine.com/articles/drivers_linux" . 

but i dont know weather it is complete code or not. because it contains only some simple functions like open, init, read, write, close.

Answer (score 0):

Linux already has a driver for the parallel port; it's called `parport`, and you can find it here:

https://github.com/torvalds/linux/tree/master/drivers/parport

Note that `parport` isn't a character device on its own. That's handled by `lp`:

https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/drivers/char/lp.c